# Getting the list of functions in an R package to be used in LaTex

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I used

```
library(help="stats")$"info"[[2]]
```

to get the list of available functions with their description in `stats`. I'd like to make a table out of this using `xtable` to be use in `Sweave` for LaTex.

I used this command in R:

```
library(xtable)
xtable(library(help="stats")$"info"[[2]])
```

and got the following error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "character"
```

I'd highly appreciate if someone guide me to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions on SO should address a specific problem, not simply ask folks to do something for you. Try first, and when you get stuck, then ask.

Comment: Thanks joran. I tried and after got stuck I post the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did the task the Patrick advises (before I saw his answer):

```
library(xtable)
library(Hmisc) # for latex()
tst<-library(help="stats")$"info"[[2]]
tdf <- data.frame(namefn = unlist(lapply(
                             strsplit(sub("\\s+", "\t", tst), "\t"), 
                             "[", 1)),
                  descrb = unlist(lapply(
                             strsplit(sub("\\s+", "\t", tst), "\t"), 
                             "[", 2)) )
xdf <- xtable(tdf)
latex(xdf, longtable=TRUE)
```

You will probably want to renames the dataframe's columns but this does get you the multi-page latex output needed to accommodate that 300+ line output that you specified.

Comment: Excellent answer, just what I was looking for too.  Just a note: `xtable` actually has an option to generate latex tables itself, `xtable(tdf, type="latex") should do the trick.  Can also be set using options(xtable.type="latex"), which is immensely useful to toggle the output format without editing the code.

Answer (score 3):

The error is indicating that `xtable` does not have a method for accepting `character` objects, such as your input. Per [the documentation for the xtable library](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/xtable.pdf), xtable accepts `data.frame` objects (among others), and also allows you to extend the library for different objects. You can see a listing of the accepted objects from `methods(xtable)`.

So my suggestion would be to load the data from `library(help="stats")$"info"[[2]]` into a data frame and pass that to `xtable` instead.